# Modal window instead alert

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to modify this script so that at the end of the allowed number of characters, instead of alert user can see a modal warning window, which disappears after N seconds. In this case, the cursor should freeze in place and further typing is impossible.
Thanks in advance for your advice.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Textbox</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/
ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
$("#contentbox").keyup(function()
{
var box=$(this).val();
var main = box.length *100;
var value= (main / 145);
var count= 145 - box.length;

if(box.length <= 145)
{
$('#count').html(count);
$('#bar').animate(
{
"width": value+'%',
}, 1);
}
else
{
alert(' Stop! ');
}
return false;
});

});
</script>
<style>
#barbox
{
float:right!; 
height:14px; 
background-color:#FFFFFF; 
width:100px; 
border:solid 2px #000; 
margin-right:3px;
margin-bottom:10px;
overflow: inherit;
}
#bar
{
background-color:#ff0000;
width:0px;
height:14px;
}
#count
{
float:right; margin-right:8px; 
font-family:'Georgia', Times New Roman, Times, serif; 
font-size:16px; 
font-weight:bold; 
color:#333;
}
#contentbox
{
width:450px; height:50px;
border:solid 2px #006699;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:14px;
}
</style>
    </head>
    <body>
<div>
<div id="count">145</div>
<div id="barbox"><div id="bar"></div></div>
</div>
<textarea id="contentbox"></textarea>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `.
.
}
else
{
alert(' Stop! ');
$("#contentbox").attr("disabled", "true");
}...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the jQuery library to create a modal dialog:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal

Here's an example using your code: http://jsfiddle.net/ZZsTS/

**JS**

```
$( "#dialog-modal" ).dialog({
  height: 140,
  modal: true,
  autoOpen: false,
  //set a timeout of 3 secs to close it again, when opened
  open: function(event, ui) {
    setTimeout("$('#dialog-modal').dialog('close')", 3000);
  },
  //when closing, make the textarea readonly
  close : function(){
    $('textarea').attr('readonly', 'readonly');
  }
});
```

**open dialog with**

```
$('#dialog-modal').dialog('open');
```

**HTML**

```
<textarea></textarea>

<div id="dialog-modal" title="Basic modal dialog">
  <p>Stop !</p>
</div>
```