# Javascript(Function to compare objects)

Tags: javascript, function, object

I am trying to create a function which will compare one music album to another but my code does not run. I'd like to know why, because I really cannot see where the problem is and why there is a problem. Thanks very much.

```
/********* GLOBAL VARIABLES *********/
var BR = "<br />";
var ES = " ";
/********* FUNCTIONS *********/

function compare(album[0], album[1]) {
    var sameAlbums = false;

    //There has to be an easier way to do all this...
    if (album[0].artistName === album[1].artistName && album[0].albumTitle === album[1].albumTitle && album[0].releaseYear === album[1].releaseYear && album[0].ifHQ === album[1].ifHQ && album[0].tracks[0] === album[1].tracks[0] && album[0].tracks[1] === album[1].tracks[1] && album[0].tracks[2] === album[1].tracks[2] && album[0].tracks[3] === album[1].tracks[3] && album[0].tracks[4] === album[1].tracks[4] && album[0].tracks[5] === album[1].tracks[5] && album[0].tracks[6] === album[1].tracks[6] && album[0].tracks[7] === album[1].tracks[7] && album[0].tracks[8] === album[1].tracks[8] && album[0].tracks[9] === album[1].tracks[9] && album[0].tracks[10] === album[1].tracks[10])

    {
        sameAlbums = true;
    }
    return sameAlbums;
}

/********* MAIN *********/

function main() {

    var alb = new album(2);


    for (var i = 0; i < album.length; i++) {
        album[i] = {
            artistName: "",
            albumTitle: "",
            releaseYear: 0,
            ifHQ: "",
            tracks: undefined //tracks here
        };
        album[i].artistName = prompt("What is the artist's name?");
        album[i].albumTitle = prompt("What is the album title?");
        album[i].releaseYear = parseFloat(prompt("What is the album's release year"));
        album[i].ifHQ = prompt("Is the album high quality? Y/N");

        while (!(album[i].ifHQ === "Y" || album[i].ifHQ === "N" || album[i].ifHQ === "YES" || album[i].ifHQ === "NO")) {
            album[i].ifHQ = prompt("You have entered an invalid response. Is " + album[i].title + " a ifHQ album, Y/N?");
            album[i].ifHQ = album[i].ifHQ.toUpperCase();
        }

        if (album[i].ifHQ === "Y") {
            album[i].ifHQ = true;
        }
        else {
            album[i].ifHQ = false;
        }
        album[i].tracks = new albumay(10);

        for (var j = 0 + 1; j < album[i].tracks.length; j++) {
            album[i].tracks[j] = prompt("Enter track" + (j + 1));


        }
    }
    for (var key in album[0]) {
        document.write(key + ": " + album[0][key] + " ");
        document.write(BR);
    }
    for (var key in album[1]) {
        document.write(key + ": " + album[1][key] + " ");
        document.write(BR);
    }

}

var same = compare(album[0], album[1]);
document.write(same);

// This line calls main, don't change it:
main();
```

Edited code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            /********* GLOBAL VARIABLES *********/
            var BR = "<br />";
            var ES = " ";
            var album = [];

            /********* FUNCTIONS *********/
            function compare(album1, album2)
            {
                for (var i in album1)
                {
                    if (album1[i] !== album2[i]) return false;
                }
                return true;
            }

            /********* MAIN *********/
            function main()
            {

                var album = [];
                var numAlbums = 3;

                for (var i = 0; i < numAlbums; i++) {

                    album[i] = {
                        artistName: "",
                        albumTitle: "",
                        releaseYear: 0,
                        ifHQ: "",
                        tracks: undefined //tracks here
                    };
                    album[i].artistName = prompt("What is the artist's name?");
                    album[i].albumTitle = prompt("What is the album title?");
                    album[i].releaseYear = parseFloat(prompt("What is the album's release year"));
                    album[i].ifHQ = prompt("Is the album high quality? Y/N");

                    while (!(album[i].ifHQ === "Y" || album[i].ifHQ === "N" || album[i].ifHQ === "YES" || album[i].ifHQ === "NO"))
                    {
                        album[i].ifHQ = prompt("You have entered an invalid response. Is " + album[i].title + " a ifHQ album, Y/N?");
                        album[i].ifHQ = album[i].ifHQ.toUpperCase();
                    }

                    if (album[i].ifHQ === "Y")
                    {
                        album[i].ifHQ = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        album[i].ifHQ = false;
                    }
                    album[i].tracks = new album(10);

                    for (var j = 0 + 1; j < album[i].tracks.length; j++)
                    {
                        album[i].tracks[j] = prompt("Enter track" + (j + 1));


                    }
                }
                for (var key in album[1])
                {
                    document.write(key + ": " + album[1][key] + " ");
                    document.write(BR);
                }
                for (var key in album[2])
                {
                    document.write(key + ": " + album[2][key] + " ");
                    document.write(BR);
                }
            }

            var same = compare(album1, album2);
            document.write(same);

            // This line calls main, don't change it:
            main();
        </script>
```

Comment: You cannot have indexes in a function argument name. It's complaining about `compare(album[0], album[1])`

Comment: but if I do function compare(album0, album1) it doesnt work either...

Comment: Did you change album[0] to album0 throughout the entire function?

Comment: album1 and album2 are not defined when you call compare. You need to define them first.

Answer (score 0):

If you run a debugger on your code, you will see that the problem is in the `compare` function. In particular, argument names cannot contain square brackets.

I would recommend changing your compare function thus:

```
function compare (album1, album2) {
    for (var i in album1) {
        if (album1[i] !== album2[i]) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I updated my code according to your advice, but firebug keeps saying that my albums are not defined.. This tells me there's a problem with the loop which creates albums and assigns numbers to them?

Comment: @ibex333 see my answer for the issue with defining the albums.  The loop is never initialized because album isn't defined.

Comment: Reworked the code, and posted edited code on top but still I have an undefined error... I am really trying to avoid asking for handouts but I just cannot see what the problem is! : (

Answer (score 0):

### Based on your update

Ok there are still plenty of issues with this code.

First and most important, album1 and album2 are not defined before being compared, for 2 reasons.

1. Main() is not executed until after they run, so album[] has not been defined
2. album[1] is not the same as album 1

### Some more things to think about:

1. Array indices start at 0 in javascript.  Skipping the first index to get your arrays to start at 1 is considered bad practice.
2. Instead of the 24 prompts you're doing right now, you should probably consider forms for input.  24 prompts in a row will be very annoying for a user.
3. You probably want a modal window for your HQ verification. Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11478441/modal-window-instead-alert)

### An attempt at cleaning up the code

I think you should probably rethink some of the choices here, but here's a cleaned up version of the code that at the very least runs:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qjST6/)

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    /********* FUNCTIONS *********/
    function compare(album1, album2)
    {
        for (var i in album1)
        {
            if (album1[i] !== album2[i]) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    /********* MAIN *********/
    function main()
    {

        var album = [];
        var numAlbums = 2;

        for (var i = 0; i < numAlbums; i++) {

            album[i] = {};
            album[i].artistName = prompt("What is the artist's name?");
            album[i].albumTitle = prompt("What is the album title?");
            album[i].releaseYear = parseFloat(prompt("What is the album's release year"));
            var hq = prompt("Is the album high quality? Y/N")
            if(!hq)
            {
                hq = "";
            }

            while (true)
            {
                hq = hq.toUpperCase();
                if( hq==="Y" || hq === "YES" )
                {
                    album[i].ifHQ = true;
                    break;
                }
                else if( hq ==="N" || hq === "NO" )
                {
                    album[i].ifHQ = false;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                hq = prompt(
                    "You have entered an invalid response. Is " + 
                    album[i].title + " a ifHQ album, Y/N?");
                }
            }
            album[i].tracks = [];

            for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            {
                album[i].tracks[j] = prompt("Enter track" + (j + 1));
            }
        }

        var same = compare(album[0], album[1]);
        document.write(same);
    }
    // This line calls main, don't change it:
    main();
</script>
```

Comment: did what you said and album1 is STILL undefined. I am trying to avoid asking for handouts, and I've been sitting her for past 15 min reworking my code but I cannot see why I still have an undefined problem...

Comment: If you're still working on this why don't you update your question with your updated code and we'll see if we can help you work from there.  Any more specific information on what you've tried and what you're seeing would help.